# Interactive fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have been a Max user for years but I am trying to learn blender now. I am working on a fluid simulation at the moment. I am using eeve as a render engine. The simulation itself is quite simple: a square domain (3x3 meters and just 5 cm high) filled with a mercury-like fluid. I got 3 cubes that I want to move around the liquid so they can interact with it.
My question is: is it possible to make those interactions in real-time, so I can see how the cubes displace the liquid around, all rendered in eeve? So far I have found that you can bake the simulation but any changes to it require to bake it again. Any help would be much appreciated